# Event that runs when object is deleted

Tags: python, scripting

I am wondering if it is possible to have a bit of code run whenever an object is deleted. Looking around I haven't seen anything that really suggests that it is possible except for maybe a **modal** operator. Is it possible, and if so how would one go about doing it.

Comment: @CoDEmanX sorry, I searched around and didn't see anything, but that does answer my question. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No problem, your question marked as duplicate will improve future search requests (because you can find words from both, and one links to the other, so you get to the place with the answer easily)